# SQL Server problems when using ODER BY and DISTINCT together

Tags: sql-server, group-by, distinct

I got two problems, the first problem is my two COUNTS that I start with. GroupID is a string that keep products together (Name_Year together), same product but different size.
If I have three reviews in tblReview and they all have the same GroupID I want to return 3. My problem is that if I have three Products with different ProductID but same GroupID and I add three Review to that GroupID I got 9 returns (3*3). If I only have one Product With the same GroupID and three Reviews it works (1*3=3 returns)

The Second problem is that if I have the ORDER BY CASE Price I have to add GROUP BY Price as well and then I don't get the DISTINCT effect that I want. And that is to just show products that have unique GroupID.

Here's the query, hope somebody can help me with this.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE GetFilterdProducts
@CategoryID INT, @ColumnName varchar(100)

AS
SELECT   COUNT(tblReview.GroupID) AS ReviewCount, 
    COUNT(tblComment.GroupID) AS CommentCount, 
    Product.ProductID, 
    Product.Name,
    Product.Year,
    Product.Price,
    Product.BrandID, 
                Product.GroupID, 
                AVG(tblReview.Grade) AS Grade


FROM            Product LEFT JOIN
                         tblComment ON Product.GroupID = tblComment.GroupID LEFT JOIN
                         tblReview ON Product.GroupID = tblReview.GroupID


WHERE        (Product.CategoryID = @CategoryID)

GROUP BY Product.ProductID, Product.BrandID, Product.GroupID, Product.Name, Product.Year, Product.Price

HAVING COUNT(distinct Product.GroupID) = 1

ORDER BY
  CASE 
  WHEN @ColumnName='Name' THEN Name
  WHEN @ColumnName='Year' THEN Year
  WHEN @ColumnName='Price' THEN Price 
  END
```

My tabels:

Product:
ProductID, Name, Year, Price, BrandID, GroupID

tblReview:
ReviewID, Description, Grade, ProductID, GroupID

tblComment:
CommentID, Description, ProductID, GroupID

I think that my problem is that if I have three GroupID with the same name, ex Nike_2010 in Product and I have three Reviews in tblReview that counts the first row in Products that contain Nike_2010 counts how many reviews in tblReview with the same GroupID, Nike_2010 and then the second row in Product that contains Nike_2010 and then do the same count again and again, that results to 9 rows. How do I avoid that?

Comment: It would be helpful if u can provide table schema, and sample input output .....

Comment: what should happen if you get three products with same group id & four reviews? how many rows would you expect to see then?

Comment: If they have the same GroupID I want 4 returns on 4 Reviews even if the have diffrent ProductID

Answer (score 0):

For starters, because you're joining on multiple tables, you're going to end up with the cross product of all of them as a result. Your counts will then return the total count of rows containing data in that column. Consider the following example:

```
- PRODUCTS -   -- COMMENTS --    --- REVIEWS ---
 Key | Name     Key | Comment     Key | Review
 1   | A        1   | Foo         1   | Great
 2   | B        1   | Bar         1   | Wonderful
```

The query

```
SELECT PRODUCTS.Key, PRODUCTS.Name, COMMENTS.Comment, REVIEWS.Review
FROM PRODUCTS
LEFT OUTER JOIN COMMENTS ON PRODUCTS.KEY = COMMENTS.KEY
LEFT OUTER JOIN REVIEWS ON PRODUCTS.KEY = REVIEWS.KEY
```

will result in the following data:

```
 Key | Name | Comment | Review
 1   | A    | Foo     | Great
 1   | A    | Foo     | Wonderful
 1   | A    | Bar     | Great
 1   | A    | Bar     | Wonderful
 2   | B    | NULL    | NULL
```

Thus, counting in this format

```
SELECT PRODUCTS.Key, PRODUCTS.Name, COUNT(COMMENTS.Comment), COUNT(REVIEWS.Review)
FROM PRODUCTS
LEFT OUTER JOIN COMMENTS ON PRODUCTS.KEY = COMMENTS.KEY
LEFT OUTER JOIN REVIEWS ON PRODUCTS.KEY = REVIEWS.KEY
GROUP BY PRODUCTS.Key, PRODUCTS.Name
```

will give you

```
Key | Name | Count1 | Count2
1   | A    | 4      | 4
2   | B    | 0      | 0
```

because it's counting each row in the table produced by the join!

Instead, you want to count each table *separately* in a subquery before joining it back like the following:

```
SELECT PRODUCTS.Key, PRODUCTS.Name, ISNULL(CommentCount.NumComments, 0),
       ISNULL(ReviewCount.NumReviews, 0)
FROM PRODUCTS
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT Key, COUNT(*) as NumComments
                 FROM COMMENTS
                 GROUP BY Key) CommentCount on PRODUCTS.Key = CommentCount.Key
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT Key, COUNT(*) as NumReviews
                 FROM REVIEWS
                 GROUP BY Key) ReviewCount on PRODUCTS.Key = ReviewCount.Key
```

which will produce the following

```
Key | Name | NumComments | NumReviews
1   | A    | 2           | 2
2   | B    | 0           | 0
```

---

As for the "DISTINCT effect" you refer to, I'm not exactly sure I follow. Could you elaborate a bit?

Comment: Okey, I think I know what you are saying, Im going to try that. My Second problem is when I list the Products I only want to display the product once. If I only display a product with a unique GroupID once. That will make sure of that products with the same GroupID (that will say Product with the same Name and same Year have the same GroupID, it's the same modell it's just diffrent length) will only be displayed once. If I add ORDER BY case Price then I have to add GROUP BY Product.Price aswell. And that takes away the DISTINCT effect.

Comment: If I add GROUP BY Price all the products are listed even if they have the same GroupID.

Comment: I dont get this part:
ISNULL(CommentCount.NumComments, 0),
       ISNULL(ReviewCount.NumReviews, 0)

Do I have to create a two new tabels where I store the number of comments/Reviews or what happens?

Comment: @Nicklas the CommentCount and ReviewCount are not new tables, but they're referencing the subqueries like `LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT .. FROM ..) CommentCount ON ..`. Look at http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189575.aspx for more help on understanding subqueries.

Comment: I'm also thinking you're really not understanding `GROUP BY`. You either want to group by price or you want to group by group id; you can't have both. If you want to sort by price, you can't group by something else because the price data disappears. Take two products A and B with prices 4 and 5, respectively. They both have the same group id. Now, if you group by id, they both get aggregated together; what is that group's resulting price? 4? 5? There's no way to know.

Answer (score 0):

About second problem - cannot you group by same CASE statement? You shouldn't have Price field in results list then though.